# Series $\sum n!\exp(-n^2)$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the series $\sum n!\exp(-n^2)$.

By the ratio test, I've proven that it is convergent (unless I made a horrible mistake).

However, I'm trying to prove this using Stirling's Formula for $n!$.

I can't go any further than:

$ n!\exp(-n^2) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \exp((n + \frac{1}{2})\ln(n) - n - n^2) $

How can I proceed? Or is there any other method without using the ratio test or Stirling's approximation? Or maybe I'm wrong and it's divergent?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You surely can estimate what of $n\log n$ and $n^2$ grows faster with $n$...

Comment: You can use Stirling's formula and the root test Sirling's formula alone won't work, as $f\sim g$ doesn't imply $\mathrm e^f \sim\mathrm e^g$.

Comment: The ratio test is *much* easier: you just consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{e^{2n+1}}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression from Stirling is good :
$$n! \exp(-n^2) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \exp\left(\left(n+ \frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(n) - n^2\right)=o\left(\exp\left(- \frac{n^2}{2} \right) \right)$$

and $\exp\left(- \frac{n^2}{2} \right) $ is the general term of a convergent series. Therefore, your series converges.